# Jquery Class Increment on append div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a dynamically-generated number at the end of "myclass" in Jquery. So I want it to increment a number at the end like this

myclass1

myclass2

myclass3

myclass4

[My code can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/1ya2vhcr/38/)

```
<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>

<div class="appendf">

</div>




 $(".clbtn").click(function(){

var f=0;

   $('.appendf').append("<div class='myclass"+f+"'>2</div>");
  f++;

});
```

Comment: Define `var f=0;` outside event handler

Comment: working.... thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `var f=0` inside the click function, on every click variable is `f` is set to `0`. Hence, you need to Move `var f=0` this outside the click function.

```js
var f = 0;
$(".clbtn").click(function() {
  $('.appendf').append("<div class='myclass" + f + "'>2</div>");
  f++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>
<div class="appendf"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The counter value of `f` is always set to `0` when clicked so move that outside the click function:

```js
var f = 0;
$(".clbtn").click(function() {
  $('<div />').addClass('myclass' + ++f).text('myclass' + f).appendTo('.appendf');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>

<div class="appendf">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

And without `f` is:

```
$(".clbtn").click(function(){
     var count = $('.appendf').find('div').length;
     $('.appendf').append("<div class='myclass"+ (count + 1) +"'>2</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define variable `f` outside click event handler to persist incremented value.

```js
var f = 0;
$(".clbtn").click(function() {
  $('<div />').addClass('myclass' + f).text('myclass' + f).appendTo('.appendf');
  f++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="clbtn" name="button" value="button">button</button>

<div class="appendf">
</div>
```